# Knockout with the help of crossroads and requirejs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am working on knockout with the help of crossroads and requirejs. The problem is that when I try to make a api call and bind it in the template, it is not binding. Please help me out on this.

This is my ViewModel

```
define(["knockout",  "knockout_mapping","text!./plp.html"], function (ko, knockout_mapping, listingTemplate) {
    var resp;


     var company;



function CompanyViewModel(data) {
    this.serverResponse=data;
    this.called = function(){
       console.log(data[0].color);
    }


}

$.ajax({

    url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cbKvZAaiBe?indent=2',
    type: 'GET', 
   dataType:'json',
    success: function(response) {
       console.log(response);

        company = new CompanyViewModel(response);
        CompanyViewModel.packageElements = ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(response));
        ko.mapping.fromJS(response,{}, this);
       // ko.applyBindings(company);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert('something went wrong: ' + response);
    }
});


 return{viewModel:company,  template: listingTemplate }
});
```

This is my template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>PLP</h2>
        </div>


             <!-- ko foreach:serverResponse --> 

<div id="company"> 
    <h1 data-bind="text:color"></h1>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:color, valueUpdate:'keyup'"/>
    <h2>Employees</h2>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>


            </tr>            
        </thead>

        <tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: firstName"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: lastName"></td>

            </tr>            
        </tbody>

    </table>

</div>
    <hr>

    <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add code to avoid post getting closed/downVoted .

Comment: I have put in the code.

Comment: You probably meant `company = ko.mapping.fromJS(company);`

Comment: The exact problem is: The viewModel is called initially at the time of page load, after that ajax is called, so binding is not happening. What is the solution for this issue which I am facing.